# Is correct use h4, h5 and h6 in common landing pages?

Tags: html

I have read in some sites that h4, h5 and h6 must be used only in articles because it can influence my SEO incorrectly.
So, my question is so simple. Can I use these tags in my landing page?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question for the reasons described in the [tag:seo] tag description.

Comment: Re edit: Removing the seo tag from your question doesn't stop it being about SEO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heading tags can influence SEO. The most important is h1 and try not to add more h1 tags in a single page to avoid confusion. Also try to make other heading tags unique. There is no problems with the h4, h5 and h6 to be used in landing page.